# Embed fonts with Ghostscript, but keep everything else as-is

Tags: ghostscript

We’re looking for software that can re-embed fonts, and Ghostscript looks like a possible solution.
We’ve been looking at the documentation, but we’re not sure how to get the result we want.

The case:
We have a PDF with all fonts embedded, but the PDF fails in our printers RIP
We have had success with using Ghostscript to subset the fonts. This seems to fix the fonts somehow, and it makes the PDF work in the printers RIP. We use this command:

C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="C:\test2.pdf" -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dCompressFonts=false -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=false -dDownsampleGrayImages=false -dDownsampleMonoImages=false -c ".setpdfwrite <[ ]>> setdistillerparams" -f "C:\test.pdf"

Now, the only thing we want to do and/or change is to subset the fonts, and keep everything "as-is" – but the command above seems to do something with the images and text.

Anyone know how to make Ghostscript just embed the fonts?

Answer (score 1):

You cna't keep everything 'as is' using the Ghostscript pdfwrite device. I've eplained this on SO before, but here goes again;

Ghostscript and pdfwrite do not simply modify an existing PDF file, the source PDF file is fully interpreted, and converted to a series of graphics primitives which are passed down to the device. Ordinarily the device would then use the graphics library to render the primitives to a bitmap. In the case of pdfwrite, the graphics primitives are re-assembled into a brand new PDF file.

What this means is that the PDF file which is produced has nothing in common with the original PDF file, other than its appearance.

Without seeing your original PDF file I can't say what might be different between the input and output, and you don't say why there is a problem. You 'might' get closer to what you want by not specifying all those command line parameters, in particular the -dPDFSETTINGS, the default behaviour is to preserve input unchanged as far as possible. However one thing you definitely will not be able to do is preserve the original file 'as is', that's just not the way the application works.